# Состояние загрузки страницы

Tags: html, javascript

Представим такой сценарий: страница загрузилась, пользователь отправляет форму, идёт загрузка другой страницы. Загрузка достаточно долгая. Пользователю надоедает ждать, и он отменяет загрузку. Вопрос: можно ли из JavaScript отследить событие отмены загрузки страницы? Данные с формы отправляются достаточно быстро, медленнен сам процесс загрузки.

Comment: Может стоит решать проблему, а не избегать её.

Comment: Нет. На загружаемой странице идёт выборка огромного массива данных из БД, ускорить её не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

только в IE есть событие **onstop**, которое срабатывает на остановку загрузки

для других браузеров можно попробовать в начале документа через **setInterval** запустить скрипт на проверку состояния **document.readyState**

при первом запуске состояние будет **loading** (документ уже начал грузится, т.к. скрипт сработал)

после остановки загрузки состояние этого параметра будет **interactive** (часть загружена, но в данный момент загрузка не идет) и еще не **loaded** и не **complete**